# Change Drop Down List Source based on user selection in another drop down

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code to change the source of the drop down list.

When a user selects a value from a list in AG3 then the source of AG4 is changed.

It works in Excel 64 but I get an error stating the procedure is too large in Excel 32.

I've tried to find out how to put all the values and source ranges in an Array.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AG3")) Is Nothing And InStr(1, Range("AG3"), "5.75") > 0 Then
    With Range("AG4").Validation
        .Delete
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
          xlBetween, Formula1:="='DropdownLists'!P2:P6"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End If
```

I paste about 100 of these just changing the user selection (5.75) and the range of the drop down list in AG4 (P2:P6). If I put these values in an Array I think I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, write the values in a sheet, like this:

```
    A  |           B            |  C   |   D    ....
   5.75| 'DropdownLists'!P2:P6  |      |
   ...
   100.
```

Then, give the range A1:B100 (or about 100 as you said) a name. (`"ArrayInRange"` in this example)

Then, you can load the values into an array as follows:

```
Dim Arr() as Variant
Arr = Range("ArrayInRange")
```

So, you can replace your event handler by this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Arr() As Variant, i As Long
    If Intersect(Target, Range("AG3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Check once instead of 100
    Arr = Range("ArrayInRange")
    For i = LBound(Arr,1) To UBound(Arr,1)
        If InStr(1, Range("AG3"), Arr(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            With Range("AG4").Validation
                .Delete
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & Arr(i, 2)
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Another solution (that might be better) is to add a third column with a formula to check if the value in column a is found within AG3
The formula in the third column will be:
`=IFERROR(FIND(A1,$AG$3),"")`

Then, you can use this event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Variant
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AG3")) Is Nothing Then 'Check once instead of 100
        R = WorksheetFunction.Match(0, Range("ArrayInRange").Parent.Columns(3), -1)
        If Not IsError(R) Then
            With Range("AG4").Validation
                .Delete
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & Range("ArrayInRange").Cells(R, 2).Value
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```